# Simple unit converter in C

Tags: c

I purchased "A Book on C" for my procedural programming class and I was going through some of the exercises. Chapter 2 Exercise 9 is about designing a unit converter that can work with ounces, pounds, grams, and kilograms.

The code I've written works, but I really think it could be done much cleaner. Using nested if statements seems like a messy way to go about this.

Also, one problem I noticed was that if a char or string is given to scanf() on line 27, it will persist and then be passed to the scanf() on line 95. For example, if you enter "y" as the value to convert, the program will goto beginning without allowing the user to answer "Would you like to perform additional conversions?" How can I go about fixing this so that if a NaN is input it is discarded?

My code can be located at:
http://pastebin.com/4tST0i7T

Comment: I recommend setting up enums - integers starting at 0 representing types. Then stick conversions into a symmetric n x n matrix. Finally, use that to find the right coefficient.

Comment: Put the code here, instead of using pastebin.

Comment: SO questions are expected to hang around, so other people can benefit from reading them and their answers.  Putting important information on other websites is counterproductive.  Please put at least the important parts of the code in your question.

Answer (score 2):

One way to clean up the if structure would be to convert the value from the "fromUnit" to a common value and then convert it to the "toUnit".  It simplifies the structure by leaving only two if structures around.  (It also scales better.)  So, it would be something more like:

```
if (!strcmp(fromUnit, "pound")) {  
    tempval = input / 16;  
} else if (!strcmp(fromUnit, "gram") == 0) {  
    tempval = input * OUNCESTOGRAMS;  
}  

if (!strcmp(toUnit, "pound")) {  
    output = tempval * 16;  
} else if (!strcmp(toUnit, "gram")) {  
    output = tempval / OUNCESTOGRAMS;  
}
```

Granted, that math isn't correct, it's just there for the example.  You would just have to (1) pick the temporary unit that you wanted to use (2) convert from the input unit to that unit and (3) convert from the temporary unit to the output unit.

And as someone else mentioned, gets() is definitely the way to go.

Comment: I was just about to suggest something similar.  Having N conversion factors is much better than having N² conversion factors.

Comment: I can't really remember the nuances of reading full strings.  I know that you would want to read the entire line at this point, though, not just a single item.

Comment: Performing the conversion twice can affect the precision.

Comment: True, but precision wasn't the question.  Simple code was the goal.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _unit {
    char * name;
    float grams;
} unit; 

unit units[] = {
    {"gram", 1.0},
    {"kilogram", 1000.0},
    {"pound", 500.0},
    {"ounce", 28.3495231}
};

unit * search_unit(char * name)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(units) / sizeof(unit)); i++)
    {
        printf("%d %s\n", i, units[i].name);
        if (0 == strcmp(units[i].name, name))
        {
            return & units[i];
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
int main() {
    char line[10];
    char unitname[10];
    int number;
    unit * found_unit;

    while (1)
    {
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        if (1 == sscanf(line, "%d", &number))
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("not a number\n");
    }

    while (1)
    {
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        sscanf(line, "%s\n", unitname);
        found_unit = search_unit(unitname);
        if (found_unit)
        {
            printf("%d %s is %f grams\n", number, unitname, found_unit->grams * number);
            break;
        }
        printf("unknown unit\n");
    }
}
```

- Store your data in some data structure, instead of in the code.
- First read a line of text, then check whether it is a number.
- When reading from stdin, take the size of the buffer into account.
- Use loops instead of goto's.
- Use some common unit, grams for example, to calculate anything to anything.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way is to read input string using **fgets()** function, check if it contains digit using **isdigit()** (all characters in string) and then convert it to numeric value using **atoi()**.

BTW, the last two operations can be replaced by **strtol()**.

Comment: _NO!_ `gets()` is unsafe, it allows buffer overruns. Use `fgets(str,len,stdin)` instead.